# Android "SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db" error when trying to get location from webview

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, webview, gps

I'm creating an android app that uses webkit with a chrome client. I want to be able to get the current location when requested from the web page. The web page I set up works for regular browsers just fine. However, when I try to access the web page in webkit, I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: 
SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
Cause - unable to open database file
external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool
WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
```

Here are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Here's my android code where I set the webview and chrome client:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        };
    });

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {  
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin,  true, false);
        }
    });
```

The javascript errors when I call:

```
navigator.geolcation.getCurrentPosition( success_function, fail_function )
```

Neither the success nor failure functions get called.

There's an extremely similar, almost identical, question here: [Android webview geoposition database failed to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984237/android-webview-geoposition-database-failed-to-open)

I've done a ton of googling, and while I see a few people with the same problem, I haven't seen a solution anywhere. If anyone needs me to provide more information, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's pretty much solved by this thread:

[Samsung Galaxy Devices can't use geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100442/samsung-galaxy-devices-cant-use-geolocation-getcurrentposition)

In short, I was using a samsung galaxy phone, and samsung galaxy phones seem to have a problem with html5 geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());
```

Geolocation uses databases to persist cached positions and permissions between sessions. 
This call sets the location of the database.